# Swift tableView setContentOffset doesn't bounce

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm having a problem understanding mechanism of `setContentOffset`, if my tableView has `contentSize.height` of 100 points and I set content offset to 200 points the table won't bounce to content like it would do if user manually scrolled tableView to 200 points. User has to tap tableView in order to bounce back to content.

Is there a way to mimic user scroll with `setContentOffset`?

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4
You can try

```
tableView.scrollToRow(at: yourIndex, at: bottom/middle/none/top, animated: true/false)
```

Place this in `ViewDidLoad` in your `TableViewController` and the tableView will begin at your desired place. If you set animated to true then you will have your desired scroll effect.

As far as `setContentOffset` that is more to simply offset the tableView so that it is positioned more correctly, not meant to mimic a scrolling action